# Different array dimensions causing failure to merge two images into one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[image]
[image]

When trying to join two images to create one:

```
img3 = imread('image_home.png')
img4 = imread('image_away.png')

result = np.hstack((img3,img4))
imwrite('Home_vs_Away.png', result)
```

This error sometimes appears:

```
all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 192 and the array at index 1 has size 191
```

How should I proceed to generate the image when there is this difference in array size when `np.hstack` does not work?

Note:
I use several images, so not always the largest image is the first and not always the largest is the second, it can be quite random which is the smallest or largest between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add a row/column with a color of your choice to match the shapes. Or you can simply let cv2.resize handle the resizing for you. In this code I show how to use both methods.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread("image_home.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("image_away.png")

# Method 1 (add a column and a row to the smallest image)
padded_img = np.ones(img1.shape, dtype="uint8")
color = np.array(img2[-1, -1])  # take the border color
padded_img[:-1, :-1, :] = img2
padded_img[-1, :, :] = color
padded_img[:, -1, :] = color

# Method 2 (let OpenCV handle the resizing)
padded_img = cv2.resize(img2, img1.shape[:2][::-1])

result = np.hstack((img1, padded_img))
cv2.imwrite("Home_vs_Away.png", result)
```

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeCorrea i use several images, so not always the largest image is the first and not always the largest is the second, it can be quite random which is the smallest or largest between the two. In this case, do you think it would be interesting to always do the resize with both or is there an option that can work with both?

Comment: And @GuilhermeCorrea using the ```shape``` to analyze which is the largest of the images and creating ```IF ELIF``` would be the fastest and smartest way to do that?

Comment: For example: ```if (img1.shape[0] > img2.shape[0]): cv2.resize(img2, img1.shape[:2][::-1])``` ```elif (img2.shape[0] > img1.shape[0]): cv2.resize(img1, img2.shape[:2][::-1]): ```?

Comment: @BrondbyIF If there isn't much variation in size, I'd choose a common shape resize everyone to the this shape. However, if shapes vary greatly, you need to consider maintaining the aspect ratio of the image, in this case I would consider padding it, you can try to maintain the image symmetrical by padding "equally" in every direction.

Comment: @BrondbyIF no need of if-elses, just get the minimum or maximum height/width

Comment: Ah ok, so ```max(img1.shape[:2][::-1], img2.shape[:2][::-1])``` is faster and usual

Comment: I suggest using np.maximum for this, python's native max won't work as expected.

Comment: Oh i see, @GuilhermeCorrea If possible, add this malleable model in your answer, it would be very good for me to understand the correct use of your indication and also useful for anyone who sees the question in the future, thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243550/discussion-between-guilherme-correa-and-brondby-if).